# How to trigger builds on minikube using Jenkins helm chart?

Tags: jenkins, minikube, kubernetes-helm

I spawn a Minikube on my laptop.

`minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --bootstrapper=kubeadm`

Initialized helm
`helm install stable/jenkins`

**Problem**

1. When I trigger a build, Jenkins-executor was waiting forever
2. Jenkins Log was stating the following

Comment: Apparently when I turned on the Logs for the Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin on my Jenkins-Master, the serviceaccount `default` had no role bindings.

Adding the following was the first step toward solving the problem

kubectl create rolebinding default \
  --clusterrole=view \
  --serviceaccount=default:default \
  --namespace=default

Comment: Next step was `# of executors` on my http://JenkinsURL/configure showed ZERO. Clearly had to add some +ive number; set it to 10 and that helped